# How to solve differential equation $y''(x)=y(x)\Big(1-\frac{\omega_1}{x}+\frac{\omega_2}{x^2}\Big)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

How to solve differential equation
$$y''(x)=y(x)\Big(1-\frac{\omega_1}{x}+\frac{\omega_2}{x^2}\Big)$$
where
$\omega_1, \omega_2$ is the any nonzero  complex number.

Answer (score 1):

A change of variable transforms it into Whittaker's equation, whose solution is given in terms of [Whittaker's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function).